# Problem about Pictures

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

$100$ pictures of BdMO math campers were painted by Benjamin . Exactly $k$ colors were used in each picture. There is a common color in every $20$ pictures. But, there is no common color in all $100$ pictures. Find the smallest possible value of $k$.

I reading solution this problem but i don’t understand
Solution:

The problem is equivalent to: There is a "universal" set $C$ of size $c$. A painter chooses $100$ sets $K_i$, each of size $c-k$, so that every element of $C$ is in at least one $K_i$, and no $20$ distinct $K_i$ can be chosen to have $C$ as their union. We wish to minimize $k$. The construction is fairly simple: make the universal set have size $21$, initially make every $K_i$ a copy of $C$, and then remove $1$ element from each $K_i$ so that every element of $C$ is removed from at least one set. This gives us $\boxed{k=20}$. Now suppose that there is a solution with $k\leq19$. In particular, we can choose some random $K_i$ to get $c-k$ elements of $C$. The other $k$ elements can then just be chosen by choosing some appropriate $K_i$ one-by-one so that the ultimate union is $C$. This gives the desired contradiction, since this process uses at most $1+k\leq 20$ sets.
Someone can explan or other solution

Comment: Who can solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two stages.  First is to prove you can do it with $21$.

Each painting has $20$ of the available $21$ colors.  If you choose $20$ paintings, there are at most $20$ colors missing, so there is at least one color common to all the paintings.  This is the pigeonhole principle.

Next is to prove you can't do it with $20$.

If there were only $20$ colors, we could pick $20$ paintings without a common color.  There must be at least one painting missing each color so there is not a common color for the $100$.  Just go through the colors and pick a painting missing it.  There is no problem if you pick the same painting twice because it is missing two colors.  If your set is less than $20$, pick some more paintings at random and you will have $20$ paintings with no common color.

Comment: can you explane If you choose 20 paintings, there are at most 20 colors missing, so there is at least one color common to all the paintings. This is the pigeonhole principle.

Comment: Try it with three colors and each two paintings has to share a common color.  Each painting has two colors, so if the colors are $R,B,W$ you can have painting that are $R,W$, some that are $B,W$, and some that are $R,B$.  Any two you select will share a color but there is no color in all the paintings.

Comment: I don’t understand why  there are at most 20
 colors missing, so there is at least one color common to all the paintings. This is the pigeonhole principle.

Comment: There are 20 paintings.  Each is missing one color.  $20 \times 1=20$ so there can only be at most $20$ colors that are not in one of the paintings.  There might be overlap in the missing colors, so there might be fewer missing among the paintings.   Since there are $21$ colors, at least one is common to the $20$ paintings.

Comment: Oh ,yes ,I will more research

Comment: But why in the first case does not have one common color of all 100 paintings

Comment: Because among the $100$ there are ones missing all $21$ colors.  That was the point of my example with three colors.  Any two share a color, but all three do not.

Comment: If replacing 100 paintings into 1000 paintings, the result is the same ?

Comment: Yes, the number $100$ doesn't matter.  You just need to eliminate the possibility that all the paintings in your group share one color.

Comment: Ok thank ross millikan